# Porting simple Scala remote actor example to Akka actors

Tags: scala, networking, akka, actor

I try to port [this simple actor example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/540906/scala-remote-actors/6769113#6769113) of sending "Ping" and "Pong" from Scala actors to Akka actors, but I keep getting errors and I wonder if it is just a simple error or some fundamental fault.

Consider this code:

```
import akka.actor.Actor._
import akka.actor.Actor

case class Message(text: String)

class PingPongActor(name: String) extends Actor {

  def receive = {
      case Message(msg) =>
        println("received: " + msg)
        Thread.sleep(1000)
        self.reply(Message("Ping"))
      case None => println("ping: timed out!")
  }
}

object Ping extends App {
  remote.start("localhost", 2552)
        .register("ping-service", actorOf(new PingPongActor("pong")))

  val actor = remote.actorFor("ping-service", "localhost", 2552)

  actor ! (Message("Ping"))
}

object Pong extends App {
  remote.start("localhost", 2553)
        .register("pong-service", actorOf(new PingPongActor("ping")))

  val actor = remote.actorFor("pong-service", "localhost", 2553)

  actor ! (Message("Pong"))
}
```

I keep getting this error:

```
received: Ping
[GENERIC] [07.10.11 23:18] [RemoteServerStarted(akka.remote.netty.NettyRemoteSupport@3ff2cea2)]
[ERROR]   [07.10.11 23:18] [akka:event-driven:dispatcher:global-2] [LocalActorRef] 
   No sender in scope, can't reply.
   You have probably:
      1. Sent a message to an Actor from an instance that is NOT an Actor.
      2. Invoked a method on an TypedActor from an instance NOT an TypedActor.
   You may want to have a look at safe_! for a variant returning a Boolean
akka.actor.IllegalActorStateException: 
   No sender in scope, can't reply.
   You have probably:
      1. Sent a message to an Actor from an instance that is NOT an Actor.
      2. Invoked a method on an TypedActor from an instance NOT an TypedActor.
   You may want to have a look at safe_! for a variant returning a Boolean
[laptop_e3263500-f129-11e0-a78d-001636ff8076]
    at akka.actor.NullChannel$.$bang(Channel.scala:177)
    at akka.actor.ActorRef$class.reply(ActorRef.scala:398)
    at akka.actor.LocalActorRef.reply(ActorRef.scala:605)
    at PingPongActor$$anonfun$receive$1.apply(RemoteActor.scala:21)
    at PingPongActor$$anonfun$receive$1.apply(RemoteActor.scala:15)
    at akka.actor.Actor$class.apply(Actor.scala:545)
    at PingPongActor.apply(RemoteActor.scala:13)
```

The idea is that I start up two applications, `Ping` and `Pong` which try to send a message to each other every second and print it on the terminal (or print an error message if no message is received for two seconds).

Comment: Um...the error message says you've sent a message to an actor from an instance that is not an actor.  Don't you need to fix that first before worrying about the remote aspect?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The biggest fundamental problem with your code is that you're sending the message from outside of an actor and so the response has no where to go. You'll notice in the original example, the initial `Message("ping")` is sent from within the `act()` loop of the `Ping` actor. But really you have a couple of issues and it's better to start over, restructuring the code a bit. Here's an example that works, but it depends on starting the clients in a particular order. Of course, you can rewrite this to keep retrying the connection from PingActor, among other things.

```
sealed trait Message
case class Ping extends Message
case class Pong extends Message

class PingActor extends Actor {

  override def preStart = {
    val pong = remote.actorFor("pong-service", "localhost", 2553)
    pong ! Ping
  }

  def receive = {
    case Pong => {
      println("Received pong")
      Thread.sleep(1000)
      self.reply(Ping)
    }
  }
}

class PongActor extends Actor {
  def receive = {
    case Ping => {
      println("Received ping")
      Thread.sleep(1000)
      self.reply(Pong)
    }
  }
}

object pingApp extends App {
  val actor = actorOf(new PingActor)
  remote.start("localhost", 2552)
        .register("ping-service", actor)
}

object pongApp extends App {
  val actor = actorOf(new PongActor)
  remote.start("localhost", 2553)
        .register("pong-service", actor)
}
```

Comment: Would I need to implement the "wait and retry until the other actor comes up"-loop inside the actor like in Scala actors or outside it?

Comment: Well, that's really up to you and how you want to design things. The key is that PingActor has to be able to get the initial reference to the remote PongActor, so if you put the retry logic outside of the actor, you would need to then pass the reference to PingActor. This could be done via a message easily enough.