# Can an actor send a message to an actor of another application running on the same machine at the same time?

Tags: scala, messaging, actor

I am interested in writing 2 actor-based Scala applications, one of them needing to send data to another one running on the same machine at the same time. Is there a way to send actor messages between different Scala applications?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/540906/scala-remote-actors

Answer (score 3):

Yes, there is. You should look at [Akka](http://akka.io), however, as it is much ahead of standard library actors for remote interaction. Besides, it is going to be merged into the standard library anyway.

With Akka, the example of how to do that is in the home page of the site.

Comment: "Besides, it is going to be merged into the standard library anyway." - how do you know that?

Comment: @Ivan It's part of the official record. Akka is part of the [Typesafe](http://www.typesafe.com/) stack and it was already declared that Akka actors would be merged back into the standard library.

Comment: Does this mean that today standard Scala actors will be deprecated then?

Comment: @Ivan The word is that hey are going to be "merged", with the best of both being used. At any rate, Scala actors have not been deprecated, and I saw no more information than this.

Answer (score 2):

You should give [Akka](http://akka.io/) a try